# Android ImageView Resize 4.1.2 vs 4.4.2

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView that needs to resize on setImageBitmap().

- On an S3 4.4.2 the image fits in perfectly
- On the S2 4.1.2 it cuts it off
- on a Pocket Neo 4.4.2 it fits

Here is part of my xml Layout:

```
<??????????????????????.ImageViewEx //extends ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainAdImage"
    android:contentDescription="Test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>
```

S2 is on the Left S3 on the Right:

[image: S2]
[image: S3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realising that I have no need for bitmap.recycle the issue seemed to have solved itself out. With 13+ (in my case) the bitmaps do not need to be manually recycled.
The way i understand their specs

Once i switched to caching as the specs state [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#inBitmap) The image sizes where fine

Answer (score 0):

I use this lib to solve that, maybe it's useful for you.

https://github.com/matabii/scale-imageview-android

Comment: Thank you for the input. I was looking for a non 3rd party lib solution.
After realising that I have no need for bitmap.recycle the issue seemed to have solved itself out. With 13+ (in my case) there bitmaps do not need to be manually recycled, The way i understand their specs.